# Table of conversion of ISO-639/ISO-3166 based language/country locale name to Windows ones and back

Tags: c++, visual-c++, localization, locale, setlocale

I want to convert POSIX locale names like `en_US`, `de_DE` that use
ISO-639-1 and ISO-3166 codes
to Windows ones `English_United States`, `German_Germany` and back.

I had found following tables on MSDN site:

- Languages http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=VS.71).aspx
- Countries http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z(v=VS.71).aspx

However they are very partial. For example these tables miss Arabic, Hebrew and many other locales that I know are supported `Hebrew_Israel`.

Where can I find fully updated tables of Windows locale names and ISO 639/3166 codes.

Note: I need it to work from Windows 2000 or at least XP to Windows 7, so I don't want to relay on
fact that Vista and 7 support BCP-47 style locale names.

**Edit:** I have an [ISO-639](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) language codes and [ISO-3166](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm) country/territory codes.  But I need to know what languages/countries are supported and how they are actually named under MSVC should I use.

Comment: I don't think there is any such table anywhere readily available. Locale names are not standardized. Why do you want this? The locale names are usually only interesting for users, less so for the code and the developer.

Comment: @wilx they are actually quite common and and very similar to standardized BCP 47. So you can expect for example that `en_US`, `de_DE` and `ar_EG` would mean same on all platforms. So I need just a list of all support Windows locales so I can map one to other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had found the answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233965.aspx

This documents includes locale ids, their names and ISO codes...

Comment: This is the only comprehensive list I was able to find of ISO and country codes; thank you! I managed to find a more easily usable version at the following link. I'm not sure how up-to-date it is, though, but it appears to cover a lot of languages and countries: http://www.localeplanet.com/dotnet/index.html