# PHP intl country code 2 chars to country name

Tags: php, locale, country, intl

I'm trying to convert, using PHP, 2 characters country codes (ISO 3166-1) to country names, or intl country codes, so I can translate the country name.

Using `Locale::getDisplayRegion` needs locale codes for languages (`nl_NL`) and all I have is the 2 characters country code. I don't want to rely on Webservices, but I can think on the geoip extension (I can't find a solution using it anyway).

Is there any way to get the 2 chars country code and convert it to localized country name without using webservices or external resources?

(I was using zend_locale some time ago, but zf2 does not have that functionality)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477555/table-of-conversion-of-iso-639-iso-3166-based-language-country-locale-name-to-wi

Comment: so grab a copy of the iso list, and stuff it into a php array. `$countries['nl_NL'] = 'Netherlands';`

Comment: Mike, your possible duplicate is related to .Net

Comment: @MarcB I have 2 chars country code, not language locale codes.

Comment: ISO 639-1 is a classification of all known languages. Since there are many languages that are spoken in more than one country, you can't map languages to countries using a one-on-one relation, which is what i understand you're trying to do.

Comment: @cuewizchris yep, you are right, the question was wrong (I edited it after your reply) the codes I have are ISO 3166-1, the ones that google maps provide for some api queries.

Comment: See this answer for the php-intl solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26307388/1329367

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You don't have to have a fully-formed locale for the first parameter. This makes the function useful for getting the country name from any locale:

```
<?php
var_dump(Locale::getDisplayRegion('-US', 'fr'));

//Returns
string 'États-Unis' (length=11)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplayregion.php#115523

Comment: To expand on this answer, the numeric region codes can also be used. `Locale::getDisplayRegion('-001', 'en')`, will output 'World'.

Comment: You need to have the "intl" Extension installed. Install it on Ubuntu whit: sudo apt install php7.1-intl

Comment: This looks much better and more elegant than everything else on this page

Answer (score 40):

Here the function with array:

```
//Edited by rezker (http://www.rezker.com)
    function code_to_country( $code ){

    $code = strtoupper($code);

    $countryList = array(
        'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
        'AX' => 'Aland Islands',
        'AL' => 'Albania',
        'DZ' => 'Algeria',
        'AS' => 'American Samoa',
        'AD' => 'Andorra',
        'AO' => 'Angola',
        'AI' => 'Anguilla',
        'AQ' => 'Antarctica',
        'AG' => 'Antigua and Barbuda',
        'AR' => 'Argentina',
        'AM' => 'Armenia',
        'AW' => 'Aruba',
        'AU' => 'Australia',
        'AT' => 'Austria',
        'AZ' => 'Azerbaijan',
        'BS' => 'Bahamas the',
        'BH' => 'Bahrain',
        'BD' => 'Bangladesh',
        'BB' => 'Barbados',
        'BY' => 'Belarus',
        'BE' => 'Belgium',
        'BZ' => 'Belize',
        'BJ' => 'Benin',
        'BM' => 'Bermuda',
        'BT' => 'Bhutan',
        'BO' => 'Bolivia',
        'BA' => 'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
        'BW' => 'Botswana',
        'BV' => 'Bouvet Island (Bouvetoya)',
        'BR' => 'Brazil',
        'IO' => 'British Indian Ocean Territory (Chagos Archipelago)',
        'VG' => 'British Virgin Islands',
        'BN' => 'Brunei Darussalam',
        'BG' => 'Bulgaria',
        'BF' => 'Burkina Faso',
        'BI' => 'Burundi',
        'KH' => 'Cambodia',
        'CM' => 'Cameroon',
        'CA' => 'Canada',
        'CV' => 'Cape Verde',
        'KY' => 'Cayman Islands',
        'CF' => 'Central African Republic',
        'TD' => 'Chad',
        'CL' => 'Chile',
        'CN' => 'China',
        'CX' => 'Christmas Island',
        'CC' => 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
        'CO' => 'Colombia',
        'KM' => 'Comoros the',
        'CD' => 'Congo',
        'CG' => 'Congo the',
        'CK' => 'Cook Islands',
        'CR' => 'Costa Rica',
        'CI' => 'Cote d\'Ivoire',
        'HR' => 'Croatia',
        'CU' => 'Cuba',
        'CY' => 'Cyprus',
        'CZ' => 'Czech Republic',
        'DK' => 'Denmark',
        'DJ' => 'Djibouti',
        'DM' => 'Dominica',
        'DO' => 'Dominican Republic',
        'EC' => 'Ecuador',
        'EG' => 'Egypt',
        'SV' => 'El Salvador',
        'GQ' => 'Equatorial Guinea',
        'ER' => 'Eritrea',
        'EE' => 'Estonia',
        'ET' => 'Ethiopia',
        'FO' => 'Faroe Islands',
        'FK' => 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
        'FJ' => 'Fiji the Fiji Islands',
        'FI' => 'Finland',
        'FR' => 'France, French Republic',
        'GF' => 'French Guiana',
        'PF' => 'French Polynesia',
        'TF' => 'French Southern Territories',
        'GA' => 'Gabon',
        'GM' => 'Gambia the',
        'GE' => 'Georgia',
        'DE' => 'Germany',
        'GH' => 'Ghana',
        'GI' => 'Gibraltar',
        'GR' => 'Greece',
        'GL' => 'Greenland',
        'GD' => 'Grenada',
        'GP' => 'Guadeloupe',
        'GU' => 'Guam',
        'GT' => 'Guatemala',
        'GG' => 'Guernsey',
        'GN' => 'Guinea',
        'GW' => 'Guinea-Bissau',
        'GY' => 'Guyana',
        'HT' => 'Haiti',
        'HM' => 'Heard Island and McDonald Islands',
        'VA' => 'Holy See (Vatican City State)',
        'HN' => 'Honduras',
        'HK' => 'Hong Kong',
        'HU' => 'Hungary',
        'IS' => 'Iceland',
        'IN' => 'India',
        'ID' => 'Indonesia',
        'IR' => 'Iran',
        'IQ' => 'Iraq',
        'IE' => 'Ireland',
        'IM' => 'Isle of Man',
        'IL' => 'Israel',
        'IT' => 'Italy',
        'JM' => 'Jamaica',
        'JP' => 'Japan',
        'JE' => 'Jersey',
        'JO' => 'Jordan',
        'KZ' => 'Kazakhstan',
        'KE' => 'Kenya',
        'KI' => 'Kiribati',
        'KP' => 'Korea',
        'KR' => 'Korea',
        'KW' => 'Kuwait',
        'KG' => 'Kyrgyz Republic',
        'LA' => 'Lao',
        'LV' => 'Latvia',
        'LB' => 'Lebanon',
        'LS' => 'Lesotho',
        'LR' => 'Liberia',
        'LY' => 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya',
        'LI' => 'Liechtenstein',
        'LT' => 'Lithuania',
        'LU' => 'Luxembourg',
        'MO' => 'Macao',
        'MK' => 'Macedonia',
        'MG' => 'Madagascar',
        'MW' => 'Malawi',
        'MY' => 'Malaysia',
        'MV' => 'Maldives',
        'ML' => 'Mali',
        'MT' => 'Malta',
        'MH' => 'Marshall Islands',
        'MQ' => 'Martinique',
        'MR' => 'Mauritania',
        'MU' => 'Mauritius',
        'YT' => 'Mayotte',
        'MX' => 'Mexico',
        'FM' => 'Micronesia',
        'MD' => 'Moldova',
        'MC' => 'Monaco',
        'MN' => 'Mongolia',
        'ME' => 'Montenegro',
        'MS' => 'Montserrat',
        'MA' => 'Morocco',
        'MZ' => 'Mozambique',
        'MM' => 'Myanmar',
        'NA' => 'Namibia',
        'NR' => 'Nauru',
        'NP' => 'Nepal',
        'AN' => 'Netherlands Antilles',
        'NL' => 'Netherlands the',
        'NC' => 'New Caledonia',
        'NZ' => 'New Zealand',
        'NI' => 'Nicaragua',
        'NE' => 'Niger',
        'NG' => 'Nigeria',
        'NU' => 'Niue',
        'NF' => 'Norfolk Island',
        'MP' => 'Northern Mariana Islands',
        'NO' => 'Norway',
        'OM' => 'Oman',
        'PK' => 'Pakistan',
        'PW' => 'Palau',
        'PS' => 'Palestinian Territory',
        'PA' => 'Panama',
        'PG' => 'Papua New Guinea',
        'PY' => 'Paraguay',
        'PE' => 'Peru',
        'PH' => 'Philippines',
        'PN' => 'Pitcairn Islands',
        'PL' => 'Poland',
        'PT' => 'Portugal, Portuguese Republic',
        'PR' => 'Puerto Rico',
        'QA' => 'Qatar',
        'RE' => 'Reunion',
        'RO' => 'Romania',
        'RU' => 'Russian Federation',
        'RW' => 'Rwanda',
        'BL' => 'Saint Barthelemy',
        'SH' => 'Saint Helena',
        'KN' => 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
        'LC' => 'Saint Lucia',
        'MF' => 'Saint Martin',
        'PM' => 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon',
        'VC' => 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
        'WS' => 'Samoa',
        'SM' => 'San Marino',
        'ST' => 'Sao Tome and Principe',
        'SA' => 'Saudi Arabia',
        'SN' => 'Senegal',
        'RS' => 'Serbia',
        'SC' => 'Seychelles',
        'SL' => 'Sierra Leone',
        'SG' => 'Singapore',
        'SK' => 'Slovakia (Slovak Republic)',
        'SI' => 'Slovenia',
        'SB' => 'Solomon Islands',
        'SO' => 'Somalia, Somali Republic',
        'ZA' => 'South Africa',
        'GS' => 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands',
        'ES' => 'Spain',
        'LK' => 'Sri Lanka',
        'SD' => 'Sudan',
        'SR' => 'Suriname',
        'SJ' => 'Svalbard & Jan Mayen Islands',
        'SZ' => 'Swaziland',
        'SE' => 'Sweden',
        'CH' => 'Switzerland, Swiss Confederation',
        'SY' => 'Syrian Arab Republic',
        'TW' => 'Taiwan',
        'TJ' => 'Tajikistan',
        'TZ' => 'Tanzania',
        'TH' => 'Thailand',
        'TL' => 'Timor-Leste',
        'TG' => 'Togo',
        'TK' => 'Tokelau',
        'TO' => 'Tonga',
        'TT' => 'Trinidad and Tobago',
        'TN' => 'Tunisia',
        'TR' => 'Turkey',
        'TM' => 'Turkmenistan',
        'TC' => 'Turks and Caicos Islands',
        'TV' => 'Tuvalu',
        'UG' => 'Uganda',
        'UA' => 'Ukraine',
        'AE' => 'United Arab Emirates',
        'GB' => 'United Kingdom',
        'US' => 'United States of America',
        'UM' => 'United States Minor Outlying Islands',
        'VI' => 'United States Virgin Islands',
        'UY' => 'Uruguay, Eastern Republic of',
        'UZ' => 'Uzbekistan',
        'VU' => 'Vanuatu',
        'VE' => 'Venezuela',
        'VN' => 'Vietnam',
        'WF' => 'Wallis and Futuna',
        'EH' => 'Western Sahara',
        'YE' => 'Yemen',
        'ZM' => 'Zambia',
        'ZW' => 'Zimbabwe'
    );

    if( !$countryList[$code] ) return $code;
    else return $countryList[$code];
    }
```

Answer (score 28):

You can get a JSON mapping of ISO2 country code to name at http://country.io/names.json. Here's a simple PHP example that makes use of it:

```
$names = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://country.io/names.json"), true);
echo $names['US'];
// => United States
echo $names['NL'];
// => Netherlands
```

See http://country.io/data/ for more related data.

Comment: and then just use "JSON to PHP array online tools" and that make sens now ---- > https://wtools.io/convert-json-to-php-array

Answer (score 0):

This is the function you want:

```
function countryCodeToCountry($code) {
    $code = strtoupper($code);
    if ($code == 'AF') return 'Afghanistan';
    if ($code == 'AX') return 'Aland Islands';
    if ($code == 'AL') return 'Albania';
    if ($code == 'DZ') return 'Algeria';
    if ($code == 'AS') return 'American Samoa';
    if ($code == 'AD') return 'Andorra';
    if ($code == 'AO') return 'Angola';
    if ($code == 'AI') return 'Anguilla';
    if ($code == 'AQ') return 'Antarctica';
    if ($code == 'AG') return 'Antigua and Barbuda';
    if ($code == 'AR') return 'Argentina';
    if ($code == 'AM') return 'Armenia';
    if ($code == 'AW') return 'Aruba';
    if ($code == 'AU') return 'Australia';
    if ($code == 'AT') return 'Austria';
    if ($code == 'AZ') return 'Azerbaijan';
    if ($code == 'BS') return 'Bahamas the';
    if ($code == 'BH') return 'Bahrain';
    if ($code == 'BD') return 'Bangladesh';
    if ($code == 'BB') return 'Barbados';
    if ($code == 'BY') return 'Belarus';
    if ($code == 'BE') return 'Belgium';
    if ($code == 'BZ') return 'Belize';
    if ($code == 'BJ') return 'Benin';
    if ($code == 'BM') return 'Bermuda';
    if ($code == 'BT') return 'Bhutan';
    if ($code == 'BO') return 'Bolivia';
    if ($code == 'BA') return 'Bosnia and Herzegovina';
    if ($code == 'BW') return 'Botswana';
    if ($code == 'BV') return 'Bouvet Island (Bouvetoya)';
    if ($code == 'BR') return 'Brazil';
    if ($code == 'IO') return 'British Indian Ocean Territory (Chagos Archipelago)';
    if ($code == 'VG') return 'British Virgin Islands';
    if ($code == 'BN') return 'Brunei Darussalam';
    if ($code == 'BG') return 'Bulgaria';
    if ($code == 'BF') return 'Burkina Faso';
    if ($code == 'BI') return 'Burundi';
    if ($code == 'KH') return 'Cambodia';
    if ($code == 'CM') return 'Cameroon';
    if ($code == 'CA') return 'Canada';
    if ($code == 'CV') return 'Cape Verde';
    if ($code == 'KY') return 'Cayman Islands';
    if ($code == 'CF') return 'Central African Republic';
    if ($code == 'TD') return 'Chad';
    if ($code == 'CL') return 'Chile';
    if ($code == 'CN') return 'China';
    if ($code == 'CX') return 'Christmas Island';
    if ($code == 'CC') return 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands';
    if ($code == 'CO') return 'Colombia';
    if ($code == 'KM') return 'Comoros the';
    if ($code == 'CD') return 'Congo';
    if ($code == 'CG') return 'Congo the';
    if ($code == 'CK') return 'Cook Islands';
    if ($code == 'CR') return 'Costa Rica';
    if ($code == 'CI') return 'Cote d\'Ivoire';
    if ($code == 'HR') return 'Croatia';
    if ($code == 'CU') return 'Cuba';
    if ($code == 'CY') return 'Cyprus';
    if ($code == 'CZ') return 'Czech Republic';
    if ($code == 'DK') return 'Denmark';
    if ($code == 'DJ') return 'Djibouti';
    if ($code == 'DM') return 'Dominica';
    if ($code == 'DO') return 'Dominican Republic';
    if ($code == 'EC') return 'Ecuador';
    if ($code == 'EG') return 'Egypt';
    if ($code == 'SV') return 'El Salvador';
    if ($code == 'GQ') return 'Equatorial Guinea';
    if ($code == 'ER') return 'Eritrea';
    if ($code == 'EE') return 'Estonia';
    if ($code == 'ET') return 'Ethiopia';
    if ($code == 'FO') return 'Faroe Islands';
    if ($code == 'FK') return 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)';
    if ($code == 'FJ') return 'Fiji the Fiji Islands';
    if ($code == 'FI') return 'Finland';
    if ($code == 'FR') return 'France, French Republic';
    if ($code == 'GF') return 'French Guiana';
    if ($code == 'PF') return 'French Polynesia';
    if ($code == 'TF') return 'French Southern Territories';
    if ($code == 'GA') return 'Gabon';
    if ($code == 'GM') return 'Gambia the';
    if ($code == 'GE') return 'Georgia';
    if ($code == 'DE') return 'Germany';
    if ($code == 'GH') return 'Ghana';
    if ($code == 'GI') return 'Gibraltar';
    if ($code == 'GR') return 'Greece';
    if ($code == 'GL') return 'Greenland';
    if ($code == 'GD') return 'Grenada';
    if ($code == 'GP') return 'Guadeloupe';
    if ($code == 'GU') return 'Guam';
    if ($code == 'GT') return 'Guatemala';
    if ($code == 'GG') return 'Guernsey';
    if ($code == 'GN') return 'Guinea';
    if ($code == 'GW') return 'Guinea-Bissau';
    if ($code == 'GY') return 'Guyana';
    if ($code == 'HT') return 'Haiti';
    if ($code == 'HM') return 'Heard Island and McDonald Islands';
    if ($code == 'VA') return 'Holy See (Vatican City State)';
    if ($code == 'HN') return 'Honduras';
    if ($code == 'HK') return 'Hong Kong';
    if ($code == 'HU') return 'Hungary';
    if ($code == 'IS') return 'Iceland';
    if ($code == 'IN') return 'India';
    if ($code == 'ID') return 'Indonesia';
    if ($code == 'IR') return 'Iran';
    if ($code == 'IQ') return 'Iraq';
    if ($code == 'IE') return 'Ireland';
    if ($code == 'IM') return 'Isle of Man';
    if ($code == 'IL') return 'Israel';
    if ($code == 'IT') return 'Italy';
    if ($code == 'JM') return 'Jamaica';
    if ($code == 'JP') return 'Japan';
    if ($code == 'JE') return 'Jersey';
    if ($code == 'JO') return 'Jordan';
    if ($code == 'KZ') return 'Kazakhstan';
    if ($code == 'KE') return 'Kenya';
    if ($code == 'KI') return 'Kiribati';
    if ($code == 'KP') return 'Korea';
    if ($code == 'KR') return 'Korea';
    if ($code == 'KW') return 'Kuwait';
    if ($code == 'KG') return 'Kyrgyz Republic';
    if ($code == 'LA') return 'Lao';
    if ($code == 'LV') return 'Latvia';
    if ($code == 'LB') return 'Lebanon';
    if ($code == 'LS') return 'Lesotho';
    if ($code == 'LR') return 'Liberia';
    if ($code == 'LY') return 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya';
    if ($code == 'LI') return 'Liechtenstein';
    if ($code == 'LT') return 'Lithuania';
    if ($code == 'LU') return 'Luxembourg';
    if ($code == 'MO') return 'Macao';
    if ($code == 'MK') return 'Macedonia';
    if ($code == 'MG') return 'Madagascar';
    if ($code == 'MW') return 'Malawi';
    if ($code == 'MY') return 'Malaysia';
    if ($code == 'MV') return 'Maldives';
    if ($code == 'ML') return 'Mali';
    if ($code == 'MT') return 'Malta';
    if ($code == 'MH') return 'Marshall Islands';
    if ($code == 'MQ') return 'Martinique';
    if ($code == 'MR') return 'Mauritania';
    if ($code == 'MU') return 'Mauritius';
    if ($code == 'YT') return 'Mayotte';
    if ($code == 'MX') return 'Mexico';
    if ($code == 'FM') return 'Micronesia';
    if ($code == 'MD') return 'Moldova';
    if ($code == 'MC') return 'Monaco';
    if ($code == 'MN') return 'Mongolia';
    if ($code == 'ME') return 'Montenegro';
    if ($code == 'MS') return 'Montserrat';
    if ($code == 'MA') return 'Morocco';
    if ($code == 'MZ') return 'Mozambique';
    if ($code == 'MM') return 'Myanmar';
    if ($code == 'NA') return 'Namibia';
    if ($code == 'NR') return 'Nauru';
    if ($code == 'NP') return 'Nepal';
    if ($code == 'AN') return 'Netherlands Antilles';
    if ($code == 'NL') return 'Netherlands the';
    if ($code == 'NC') return 'New Caledonia';
    if ($code == 'NZ') return 'New Zealand';
    if ($code == 'NI') return 'Nicaragua';
    if ($code == 'NE') return 'Niger';
    if ($code == 'NG') return 'Nigeria';
    if ($code == 'NU') return 'Niue';
    if ($code == 'NF') return 'Norfolk Island';
    if ($code == 'MP') return 'Northern Mariana Islands';
    if ($code == 'NO') return 'Norway';
    if ($code == 'OM') return 'Oman';
    if ($code == 'PK') return 'Pakistan';
    if ($code == 'PW') return 'Palau';
    if ($code == 'PS') return 'Palestinian Territory';
    if ($code == 'PA') return 'Panama';
    if ($code == 'PG') return 'Papua New Guinea';
    if ($code == 'PY') return 'Paraguay';
    if ($code == 'PE') return 'Peru';
    if ($code == 'PH') return 'Philippines';
    if ($code == 'PN') return 'Pitcairn Islands';
    if ($code == 'PL') return 'Poland';
    if ($code == 'PT') return 'Portugal, Portuguese Republic';
    if ($code == 'PR') return 'Puerto Rico';
    if ($code == 'QA') return 'Qatar';
    if ($code == 'RE') return 'Reunion';
    if ($code == 'RO') return 'Romania';
    if ($code == 'RU') return 'Russian Federation';
    if ($code == 'RW') return 'Rwanda';
    if ($code == 'BL') return 'Saint Barthelemy';
    if ($code == 'SH') return 'Saint Helena';
    if ($code == 'KN') return 'Saint Kitts and Nevis';
    if ($code == 'LC') return 'Saint Lucia';
    if ($code == 'MF') return 'Saint Martin';
    if ($code == 'PM') return 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon';
    if ($code == 'VC') return 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines';
    if ($code == 'WS') return 'Samoa';
    if ($code == 'SM') return 'San Marino';
    if ($code == 'ST') return 'Sao Tome and Principe';
    if ($code == 'SA') return 'Saudi Arabia';
    if ($code == 'SN') return 'Senegal';
    if ($code == 'RS') return 'Serbia';
    if ($code == 'SC') return 'Seychelles';
    if ($code == 'SL') return 'Sierra Leone';
    if ($code == 'SG') return 'Singapore';
    if ($code == 'SK') return 'Slovakia (Slovak Republic)';
    if ($code == 'SI') return 'Slovenia';
    if ($code == 'SB') return 'Solomon Islands';
    if ($code == 'SO') return 'Somalia, Somali Republic';
    if ($code == 'ZA') return 'South Africa';
    if ($code == 'GS') return 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands';
    if ($code == 'ES') return 'Spain';
    if ($code == 'LK') return 'Sri Lanka';
    if ($code == 'SD') return 'Sudan';
    if ($code == 'SR') return 'Suriname';
    if ($code == 'SJ') return 'Svalbard & Jan Mayen Islands';
    if ($code == 'SZ') return 'Swaziland';
    if ($code == 'SE') return 'Sweden';
    if ($code == 'CH') return 'Switzerland, Swiss Confederation';
    if ($code == 'SY') return 'Syrian Arab Republic';
    if ($code == 'TW') return 'Taiwan';
    if ($code == 'TJ') return 'Tajikistan';
    if ($code == 'TZ') return 'Tanzania';
    if ($code == 'TH') return 'Thailand';
    if ($code == 'TL') return 'Timor-Leste';
    if ($code == 'TG') return 'Togo';
    if ($code == 'TK') return 'Tokelau';
    if ($code == 'TO') return 'Tonga';
    if ($code == 'TT') return 'Trinidad and Tobago';
    if ($code == 'TN') return 'Tunisia';
    if ($code == 'TR') return 'Turkey';
    if ($code == 'TM') return 'Turkmenistan';
    if ($code == 'TC') return 'Turks and Caicos Islands';
    if ($code == 'TV') return 'Tuvalu';
    if ($code == 'UG') return 'Uganda';
    if ($code == 'UA') return 'Ukraine';
    if ($code == 'AE') return 'United Arab Emirates';
    if ($code == 'GB') return 'United Kingdom';
    if ($code == 'US') return 'United States of America';
    if ($code == 'UM') return 'United States Minor Outlying Islands';
    if ($code == 'VI') return 'United States Virgin Islands';
    if ($code == 'UY') return 'Uruguay, Eastern Republic of';
    if ($code == 'UZ') return 'Uzbekistan';
    if ($code == 'VU') return 'Vanuatu';
    if ($code == 'VE') return 'Venezuela';
    if ($code == 'VN') return 'Vietnam';
    if ($code == 'WF') return 'Wallis and Futuna';
    if ($code == 'EH') return 'Western Sahara';
    if ($code == 'YE') return 'Yemen';
    if ($code == 'XK') return 'Kosovo';
    if ($code == 'ZM') return 'Zambia';
    if ($code == 'ZW') return 'Zimbabwe';
    return '';
}
```

Comment: You should add in a default `$code` like: `function country_code_to_country( $code = 'US' ) {`

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't you use an array?

Comment: Worst written function ever... he's not even using `elseif`s, so all the ifs must be evaluated even if the first one matches

Comment: @the_nuts wrong:the return statement stop the evaluation. right: it's a bad function

Comment: @ludofleury the answer was edited 10 days ago, look how it was when I wrote the comment

Comment: There are various downsides to this approach. Mainly without them being in an array you are entirely stuck with using this function AND only when you have the CC. what if I only have the country name? If in an array I can check value based on key, or key based on value. I can do various other things with it too. This is way too much code to be hardcoded to one potential use case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late...

I wrote a small library in order to do this and some other ISO related things.

https://github.com/php-components/isocodes

Would be great to get some feedback or even pull requests in order to impove that library.

```
use ISOCodes\ISO3166_1\Adapter\Json as ISO3166_1Adapter;

$countryAdapter = new ISO3166_1Adapter();
// Get the country with alpha-2 code 'NL'
$country = $countryAdapter->get('nl');

if (null === $country) {
    die('Country not found!');
}

// Get the french (fr) name.
echo $country->getName('fr');
```

The result would be `Pays-Bas`

You can use alpha-2, alpha-3 or numeric code to do the country search.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

/* --------------------------------------- /
 * XX. IP and country (Market).
 * -------------------------------------- */

// Gets client's IP.
$ip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP")?:
getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")?:
getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED")?:
getenv("HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR")?:
getenv("HTTP_FORWARDED")?:
getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

// CURL init. Matchs gotten IP with API values and retrives location value.
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
// json output.
$output = curl_exec($curl);
// CURL close.
curl_close($curl);

// "Country code to name" array.
$countries = array( "BD" => "Bangladesh", "BE" => "Belgium", "BF" => "Burkina Faso", "BG" => "Bulgaria", "BA" => "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BB" => "Barbados", "WF" => "Wallis and Futuna", "BL" => "Saint Barthelemy", "BM" => "Bermuda", "BN" => "Brunei", "BO" => "Bolivia", "BH" => "Bahrain", "BI" => "Burundi", "BJ" => "Benin", "BT" => "Bhutan", "JM" => "Jamaica", "BV" => "Bouvet Island", "BW" => "Botswana", "WS" => "Samoa", "BQ" => "Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba ", "BR" => "Brazil", "BS" => "Bahamas", "JE" => "Jersey", "BY" => "Belarus", "BZ" => "Belize", "RU" => "Russia", "RW" => "Rwanda", "RS" => "Serbia", "TL" => "East Timor", "RE" => "Reunion", "TM" => "Turkmenistan", "TJ" => "Tajikistan", "RO" => "Romania", "TK" => "Tokelau", "GW" => "Guinea-Bissau", "GU" => "Guam", "GT" => "Guatemala", "GS" => "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "GR" => "Greece", "GQ" => "Equatorial Guinea", "GP" => "Guadeloupe", "JP" => "Japan", "GY" => "Guyana", "GG" => "Guernsey", "GF" => "French Guiana", "GE" => "Georgia", "GD" => "Grenada", "GB" => "United Kingdom", "GA" => "Gabon", "SV" => "El Salvador", "GN" => "Guinea", "GM" => "Gambia", "GL" => "Greenland", "GI" => "Gibraltar", "GH" => "Ghana", "OM" => "Oman", "TN" => "Tunisia", "JO" => "Jordan", "HR" => "Croatia", "HT" => "Haiti", "HU" => "Hungary", "HK" => "Hong Kong", "HN" => "Honduras", "HM" => "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "VE" => "Venezuela", "PR" => "Puerto Rico", "PS" => "Palestinian Territory", "PW" => "Palau", "PT" => "Portugal", "SJ" => "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "PY" => "Paraguay", "IQ" => "Iraq", "PA" => "Panama", "PF" => "French Polynesia", "PG" => "Papua New Guinea", "PE" => "Peru", "PK" => "Pakistan", "PH" => "Philippines", "PN" => "Pitcairn", "PL" => "Poland", "PM" => "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "ZM" => "Zambia", "EH" => "Western Sahara", "EE" => "Estonia", "EG" => "Egypt", "ZA" => "South Africa", "EC" => "Ecuador", "IT" => "Italy", "VN" => "Vietnam", "SB" => "Solomon Islands", "ET" => "Ethiopia", "SO" => "Somalia", "ZW" => "Zimbabwe", "SA" => "Saudi Arabia", "ES" => "Spain", "ER" => "Eritrea", "ME" => "Montenegro", "MD" => "Moldova", "MG" => "Madagascar", "MF" => "Saint Martin", "MA" => "Morocco", "MC" => "Monaco", "UZ" => "Uzbekistan", "MM" => "Myanmar", "ML" => "Mali", "MO" => "Macao", "MN" => "Mongolia", "MH" => "Marshall Islands", "MK" => "Macedonia", "MU" => "Mauritius", "MT" => "Malta", "MW" => "Malawi", "MV" => "Maldives", "MQ" => "Martinique", "MP" => "Northern Mariana Islands", "MS" => "Montserrat", "MR" => "Mauritania", "IM" => "Isle of Man", "UG" => "Uganda", "TZ" => "Tanzania", "MY" => "Malaysia", "MX" => "Mexico", "IL" => "Israel", "FR" => "France", "IO" => "British Indian Ocean Territory", "SH" => "Saint Helena", "FI" => "Finland", "FJ" => "Fiji", "FK" => "Falkland Islands", "FM" => "Micronesia", "FO" => "Faroe Islands", "NI" => "Nicaragua", "NL" => "Netherlands", "NO" => "Norway", "NA" => "Namibia", "VU" => "Vanuatu", "NC" => "New Caledonia", "NE" => "Niger", "NF" => "Norfolk Island", "NG" => "Nigeria", "NZ" => "New Zealand", "NP" => "Nepal", "NR" => "Nauru", "NU" => "Niue", "CK" => "Cook Islands", "XK" => "Kosovo", "CI" => "Ivory Coast", "CH" => "Switzerland", "CO" => "Colombia", "CN" => "China", "CM" => "Cameroon", "CL" => "Chile", "CC" => "Cocos Islands", "CA" => "Canada", "CG" => "Republic of the Congo", "CF" => "Central African Republic", "CD" => "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "CZ" => "Czech Republic", "CY" => "Cyprus", "CX" => "Christmas Island", "CR" => "Costa Rica", "CW" => "Curacao", "CV" => "Cape Verde", "CU" => "Cuba", "SZ" => "Swaziland", "SY" => "Syria", "SX" => "Sint Maarten", "KG" => "Kyrgyzstan", "KE" => "Kenya", "SS" => "South Sudan", "SR" => "Suriname", "KI" => "Kiribati", "KH" => "Cambodia", "KN" => "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "KM" => "Comoros", "ST" => "Sao Tome and Principe", "SK" => "Slovakia", "KR" => "South Korea", "SI" => "Slovenia", "KP" => "North Korea", "KW" => "Kuwait", "SN" => "Senegal", "SM" => "San Marino", "SL" => "Sierra Leone", "SC" => "Seychelles", "KZ" => "Kazakhstan", "KY" => "Cayman Islands", "SG" => "Singapore", "SE" => "Sweden", "SD" => "Sudan", "DO" => "Dominican Republic", "DM" => "Dominica", "DJ" => "Djibouti", "DK" => "Denmark", "VG" => "British Virgin Islands", "DE" => "Germany", "YE" => "Yemen", "DZ" => "Algeria", "US" => "United States", "UY" => "Uruguay", "YT" => "Mayotte", "UM" => "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "LB" => "Lebanon", "LC" => "Saint Lucia", "LA" => "Laos", "TV" => "Tuvalu", "TW" => "Taiwan", "TT" => "Trinidad and Tobago", "TR" => "Turkey", "LK" => "Sri Lanka", "LI" => "Liechtenstein", "LV" => "Latvia", "TO" => "Tonga", "LT" => "Lithuania", "LU" => "Luxembourg", "LR" => "Liberia", "LS" => "Lesotho", "TH" => "Thailand", "TF" => "French Southern Territories", "TG" => "Togo", "TD" => "Chad", "TC" => "Turks and Caicos Islands", "LY" => "Libya", "VA" => "Vatican", "VC" => "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "AE" => "United Arab Emirates", "AD" => "Andorra", "AG" => "Antigua and Barbuda", "AF" => "Afghanistan", "AI" => "Anguilla", "VI" => "U.S. Virgin Islands", "IS" => "Iceland", "IR" => "Iran", "AM" => "Armenia", "AL" => "Albania", "AO" => "Angola", "AQ" => "Antarctica", "AS" => "American Samoa", "AR" => "Argentina", "AU" => "Australia", "AT" => "Austria", "AW" => "Aruba", "IN" => "India", "AX" => "Aland Islands", "AZ" => "Azerbaijan", "IE" => "Ireland", "ID" => "Indonesia", "UA" => "Ukraine", "QA" => "Qatar", "MZ" => "Mozambique" );

// Assigns ISO Alpha-2 value to the variable "&country_code".
$country_code = json_decode($output, true);
// Assigns "$country_name" value after checking array.
$country_name = $countries[$country_code["country"]];

echo $country_name;

?>
```

100% tested and working OK. See it in action [here](http://www.rafaeloliveros.com/country/). Im using it in many projects and it's working like a charm.

Answer (score -10):

```
<?php
echo country_name("DZ");
function country_name($value){
     if($value=="AF"){return "Afghanistan";}
     elseif($value=="AX"){return "Åland Islands";}
     elseif($value=="AL"){return "Albania";}
     elseif($value=="DZ"){return "Algeria";}
     elseif($value=="AS"){return "American Samoa";}
     elseif($value=="AD"){return "Andorra";}
     elseif($value=="AO"){return "Angola";}
     elseif($value=="AI"){return "Anguilla";}
     elseif($value=="AQ"){return "Antarctica";}
     elseif($value=="AG"){return "Antigua and Barbuda";}
     elseif($value=="AR"){return "Argentina";}
     elseif($value=="AM"){return "Armenia";}
     elseif($value=="AW"){return "Aruba";}
     elseif($value=="AU"){return "Australia";}
     elseif($value=="AT"){return "Austria";}
     elseif($value=="AZ"){return "Azerbaijan";}
     elseif($value=="BS"){return "Bahamas";}
     elseif($value=="BH"){return "Bahrain";}
     elseif($value=="BD"){return "Bangladesh";}
     elseif($value=="BB"){return "Barbados";}
     elseif($value=="BY"){return "Belarus";}
     elseif($value=="BE"){return "Belgium";}
     elseif($value=="BZ"){return "Belize";}
     elseif($value=="BJ"){return "Benin";}
     elseif($value=="BM"){return "Bermuda";}
     elseif($value=="BT"){return "Bhutan";}
     elseif($value=="BO"){return "Bolivia, Plurinational State of";}
     elseif($value=="BQ"){return "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba";}
     elseif($value=="BA"){return "Bosnia and Herzegovina";}
     elseif($value=="BW"){return "Botswana";}
     elseif($value=="BV"){return "Bouvet Island";}
     elseif($value=="BR"){return "Brazil";}
     elseif($value=="IO"){return "British Indian Ocean Territory";}
     elseif($value=="BN"){return "Brunei Darussalam";}
     elseif($value=="BG"){return "Bulgaria";}
     elseif($value=="BF"){return "Burkina Faso";}
     elseif($value=="BI"){return "Burundi";}
     elseif($value=="KH"){return "Cambodia";}
     elseif($value=="CM"){return "Cameroon";}
     elseif($value=="CA"){return "Canada";}
     elseif($value=="CV"){return "Cape Verde";}
     elseif($value=="KY"){return "Cayman Islands";}
     elseif($value=="CF"){return "Central African Republic";}
     elseif($value=="TD"){return "Chad";}
     elseif($value=="CL"){return "Chile";}
     elseif($value=="CN"){return "China";}
     elseif($value=="CX"){return "Christmas Island";}
     elseif($value=="CC"){return "Cocos (Keeling) Islands";}
     elseif($value=="CO"){return "Colombia";}
     elseif($value=="KM"){return "Comoros";}
     elseif($value=="CG"){return "Congo";}
     elseif($value=="CD"){return "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the";}
     elseif($value=="CK"){return "Cook Islands";}
     elseif($value=="CR"){return "Costa Rica";}
     elseif($value=="CI"){return "Côte d'Ivoire";}
     elseif($value=="HR"){return "Croatia";}
     elseif($value=="CU"){return "Cuba";}
     elseif($value=="CW"){return "Curaçao";}
     elseif($value=="CY"){return "Cyprus";}
     elseif($value=="CZ"){return "Czech Republic";}
     elseif($value=="DK"){return "Denmark";}
     elseif($value=="DJ"){return "Djibouti";}
     elseif($value=="DM"){return "Dominica";}
     elseif($value=="DO"){return "Dominican Republic";}
     elseif($value=="EC"){return "Ecuador";}
     elseif($value=="EG"){return "Egypt";}
     elseif($value=="SV"){return "El Salvador";}
     elseif($value=="GQ"){return "Equatorial Guinea";}
     elseif($value=="ER"){return "Eritrea";}
     elseif($value=="EE"){return "Estonia";}
     elseif($value=="ET"){return "Ethiopia";}
     elseif($value=="FK"){return "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)";}
     elseif($value=="FO"){return "Faroe Islands";}
     elseif($value=="FJ"){return "Fiji";}
     elseif($value=="FI"){return "Finland";}
     elseif($value=="FR"){return "France";}
     elseif($value=="GF"){return "French Guiana";}
     elseif($value=="PF"){return "French Polynesia";}
     elseif($value=="TF"){return "French Southern Territories";}
     elseif($value=="GA"){return "Gabon";}
     elseif($value=="GM"){return "Gambia";}
     elseif($value=="GE"){return "Georgia";}
     elseif($value=="DE"){return "Germany";}
     elseif($value=="GH"){return "Ghana";}
     elseif($value=="GI"){return "Gibraltar";}
     elseif($value=="GR"){return "Greece";}
     elseif($value=="GL"){return "Greenland";}
     elseif($value=="GD"){return "Grenada";}
     elseif($value=="GP"){return "Guadeloupe";}
     elseif($value=="GU"){return "Guam";}
     elseif($value=="GT"){return "Guatemala";}
     elseif($value=="GG"){return "Guernsey";}
     elseif($value=="GN"){return "Guinea";}
     elseif($value=="GW"){return "Guinea-Bissau";}
     elseif($value=="GY"){return "Guyana";}
     elseif($value=="HT"){return "Haiti";}
     elseif($value=="HM"){return "Heard Island and McDonald Islands";}
     elseif($value=="VA"){return "Holy See (Vatican City State)";}
     elseif($value=="HN"){return "Honduras";}
     elseif($value=="HK"){return "Hong Kong";}
     elseif($value=="HU"){return "Hungary";}
     elseif($value=="IS"){return "Iceland";}
     elseif($value=="IN"){return "India";}
     elseif($value=="ID"){return "Indonesia";}
     elseif($value=="IR"){return "Iran, Islamic Republic of";}
     elseif($value=="IQ"){return "Iraq";}
     elseif($value=="IE"){return "Ireland";}
     elseif($value=="IM"){return "Isle of Man";}
     elseif($value=="IL"){return "Israel";}
     elseif($value=="IT"){return "Italy";}
     elseif($value=="JM"){return "Jamaica";}
     elseif($value=="JP"){return "Japan";}
     elseif($value=="JE"){return "Jersey";}
     elseif($value=="JO"){return "Jordan";}
     elseif($value=="KZ"){return "Kazakhstan";}
     elseif($value=="KE"){return "Kenya";}
     elseif($value=="KI"){return "Kiribati";}
     elseif($value=="KP"){return "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of";}
     elseif($value=="KR"){return "Korea, Republic of";}
     elseif($value=="KW"){return "Kuwait";}
     elseif($value=="KG"){return "Kyrgyzstan";}
     elseif($value=="LA"){return "Lao People's Democratic Republic";}
     elseif($value=="LV"){return "Latvia";}
     elseif($value=="LB"){return "Lebanon";}
     elseif($value=="LS"){return "Lesotho";}
     elseif($value=="LR"){return "Liberia";}
     elseif($value=="LY"){return "Libya";}
     elseif($value=="LI"){return "Liechtenstein";}
     elseif($value=="LT"){return "Lithuania";}
     elseif($value=="LU"){return "Luxembourg";}
     elseif($value=="MO"){return "Macao";}
     elseif($value=="MK"){return "Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of";}
     elseif($value=="MG"){return "Madagascar";}
     elseif($value=="MW"){return "Malawi";}
     elseif($value=="MY"){return "Malaysia";}
     elseif($value=="MV"){return "Maldives";}
     elseif($value=="ML"){return "Mali";}
     elseif($value=="MT"){return "Malta";}
     elseif($value=="MH"){return "Marshall Islands";}
     elseif($value=="MQ"){return "Martinique";}
     elseif($value=="MR"){return "Mauritania";}
     elseif($value=="MU"){return "Mauritius";}
     elseif($value=="YT"){return "Mayotte";}
     elseif($value=="MX"){return "Mexico";}
     elseif($value=="FM"){return "Micronesia, Federated States of";}
     elseif($value=="MD"){return "Moldova, Republic of";}
     elseif($value=="MC"){return "Monaco";}
     elseif($value=="MN"){return "Mongolia";}
     elseif($value=="ME"){return "Montenegro";}
     elseif($value=="MS"){return "Montserrat";}
     elseif($value=="MA"){return "Morocco";}
     elseif($value=="MZ"){return "Mozambique";}
     elseif($value=="MM"){return "Myanmar";}
     elseif($value=="NA"){return "Namibia";}
     elseif($value=="NR"){return "Nauru";}
     elseif($value=="NP"){return "Nepal";}
     elseif($value=="NL"){return "Netherlands";}
     elseif($value=="NC"){return "New Caledonia";}
     elseif($value=="NZ"){return "New Zealand";}
     elseif($value=="NI"){return "Nicaragua";}
     elseif($value=="NE"){return "Niger";}
     elseif($value=="NG"){return "Nigeria";}
     elseif($value=="NU"){return "Niue";}
     elseif($value=="NF"){return "Norfolk Island";}
     elseif($value=="MP"){return "Northern Mariana Islands";}
     elseif($value=="NO"){return "Norway";}
     elseif($value=="OM"){return "Oman";}
     elseif($value=="PK"){return "Pakistan";}
     elseif($value=="PW"){return "Palau";}
     elseif($value=="PS"){return "Palestinian Territory, Occupied";}
     elseif($value=="PA"){return "Panama";}
     elseif($value=="PG"){return "Papua New Guinea";}
     elseif($value=="PY"){return "Paraguay";}
     elseif($value=="PE"){return "Peru";}
     elseif($value=="PH"){return "Philippines";}
     elseif($value=="PN"){return "Pitcairn";}
     elseif($value=="PL"){return "Poland";}
     elseif($value=="PT"){return "Portugal";}
     elseif($value=="PR"){return "Puerto Rico";}
     elseif($value=="QA"){return "Qatar";}
     elseif($value=="RE"){return "Réunion";}
     elseif($value=="RO"){return "Romania";}
     elseif($value=="RU"){return "Russian Federation";}
     elseif($value=="RW"){return "Rwanda";}
     elseif($value=="BL"){return "Saint Barthélemy";}
     elseif($value=="SH"){return "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha";}
     elseif($value=="KN"){return "Saint Kitts and Nevis";}
     elseif($value=="LC"){return "Saint Lucia";}
     elseif($value=="MF"){return "Saint Martin (French part)";}
     elseif($value=="PM"){return "Saint Pierre and Miquelon";}
     elseif($value=="VC"){return "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines";}
     elseif($value=="WS"){return "Samoa";}
     elseif($value=="SM"){return "San Marino";}
     elseif($value=="ST"){return "Sao Tome and Principe";}
     elseif($value=="SA"){return "Saudi Arabia";}
     elseif($value=="SN"){return "Senegal";}
     elseif($value=="RS"){return "Serbia";}
     elseif($value=="SC"){return "Seychelles";}
     elseif($value=="SL"){return "Sierra Leone";}
     elseif($value=="SG"){return "Singapore";}
     elseif($value=="SX"){return "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)";}
     elseif($value=="SK"){return "Slovakia";}
     elseif($value=="SI"){return "Slovenia";}
     elseif($value=="SB"){return "Solomon Islands";}
     elseif($value=="SO"){return "Somalia";}
     elseif($value=="ZA"){return "South Africa";}
     elseif($value=="GS"){return "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands";}
     elseif($value=="SS"){return "South Sudan";}
     elseif($value=="ES"){return "Spain";}
     elseif($value=="LK"){return "Sri Lanka";}
     elseif($value=="SD"){return "Sudan";}
     elseif($value=="SR"){return "Suriname";}
     elseif($value=="SJ"){return "Svalbard and Jan Mayen";}
     elseif($value=="SZ"){return "Swaziland";}
     elseif($value=="SE"){return "Sweden";}
     elseif($value=="CH"){return "Switzerland";}
     elseif($value=="SY"){return "Syrian Arab Republic";}
     elseif($value=="TW"){return "Taiwan, Province of China";}
     elseif($value=="TJ"){return "Tajikistan";}
     elseif($value=="TZ"){return "Tanzania, United Republic of";}
     elseif($value=="TH"){return "Thailand";}
     elseif($value=="TL"){return "Timor-Leste";}
     elseif($value=="TG"){return "Togo";}
     elseif($value=="TK"){return "Tokelau";}
     elseif($value=="TO"){return "Tonga";}
     elseif($value=="TT"){return "Trinidad and Tobago";}
     elseif($value=="TN"){return "Tunisia";}
     elseif($value=="TR"){return "Turkey";}
     elseif($value=="TM"){return "Turkmenistan";}
     elseif($value=="TC"){return "Turks and Caicos Islands";}
     elseif($value=="TV"){return "Tuvalu";}
     elseif($value=="UG"){return "Uganda";}
     elseif($value=="UA"){return "Ukraine";}
     elseif($value=="AE"){return "United Arab Emirates";}
     elseif($value=="GB"){return "United Kingdom";}
     elseif($value=="US"){return "United States";}
     elseif($value=="UM"){return "United States Minor Outlying Islands";}
     elseif($value=="UY"){return "Uruguay";}
     elseif($value=="UZ"){return "Uzbekistan";}
     elseif($value=="VU"){return "Vanuatu";}
     elseif($value=="VE"){return "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of";}
     elseif($value=="VN"){return "Viet Nam";}
     elseif($value=="VG"){return "Virgin Islands, British";}
     elseif($value=="VI"){return "Virgin Islands, U.S.";}
     elseif($value=="WF"){return "Wallis and Futuna";}
     elseif($value=="EH"){return "Western Sahara";}
     elseif($value=="YE"){return "Yemen";}
     elseif($value=="ZM"){return "Zambia";}
     elseif($value=="ZW"){return "Zimbabwe";}
     else{return "Unknown Country";}
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Good lord, why on earth would you use if/elseif here?