# Country language name to ISO code initials with PHP

Tags: php, localization, iso

For a jobs table, I'm looking for a way to get the ISO code initials from a country.
I've got the full name but I want the 2 character name.

For example: 
"United States" turns into "US" or "Netherlands" turns into "NL".

**My code is this:**

```
$locations = array();

$args = array (
    'taxonomy' => 'location',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$get_locations = get_terms($args);

foreach ($get_locations as $key => $location) {
    $jobs_array = array();
    $location_name = $location->name;
    
    // Get jobs
    $post_type = 'jobs';
    $posts_per_page = -1;
    $jobs_args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'location' => $location_slug,
    );
    
    $jobs = new WP_Query( $jobs_args );
    
    if($jobs->have_posts()) :
        while ( $jobs->have_posts() ): $jobs->the_post();
        // $jobs_array = $post;
        $jobs_array[] = $post->post_title;
        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    
    $locations[$location_slug] = $jobs_array;
}
```

**What result into:**

[image: array_result]

As you can see, the key is the full name.
I hope someone knows how to achieve this. Thanks!

This question is also posted on the WordPress Stack Exchange, as it's using a query loop from WordPress posts.

Comment: Check this post,  [PHP intl country code 2 chars to country name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842003/php-intl-country-code-2-chars-to-country-name)

Comment: @Milad, I know that. I want to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did understand everything correctly, you want the ARRAY KEY to contain the Country ISO code instead of the full name right?

I would suggest to create a custom class which contains an array with the country names and ISO codes. Something like this:

```
<?php

class CountryIsoCodes
{
    const COUNTRIES = [
    'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
    'AX' => 'Aland Islands',
    'AL' => 'Albania',
    'DZ' => 'Algeria',
    'AS' => 'American Samoa',
    'AD' => 'Andorra',
    'AO' => 'Angola',
    'AI' => 'Anguilla',
    'AQ' => 'Antarctica',
    'AG' => 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    'AR' => 'Argentina',
    'AM' => 'Armenia',
    'AW' => 'Aruba',
    'AU' => 'Australia',
    'AT' => 'Austria',
    'AZ' => 'Azerbaijan',
    'BS' => 'Bahamas the',
    'BH' => 'Bahrain',
    'BD' => 'Bangladesh',
    'BB' => 'Barbados',
    'BY' => 'Belarus',
    'BE' => 'Belgium',
    'BZ' => 'Belize',
    'BJ' => 'Benin',
    'BM' => 'Bermuda',
    'BT' => 'Bhutan',
    'BO' => 'Bolivia',
    'BA' => 'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
    'BW' => 'Botswana',
    'BV' => 'Bouvet Island (Bouvetoya)',
    'BR' => 'Brazil',
    'IO' => 'British Indian Ocean Territory (Chagos Archipelago)',
    'VG' => 'British Virgin Islands',
    'BN' => 'Brunei Darussalam',
    'BG' => 'Bulgaria',
    'BF' => 'Burkina Faso',
    'BI' => 'Burundi',
    'KH' => 'Cambodia',
    'CM' => 'Cameroon',
    'CA' => 'Canada',
    'CV' => 'Cape Verde',
    'KY' => 'Cayman Islands',
    'CF' => 'Central African Republic',
    'TD' => 'Chad',
    'CL' => 'Chile',
    'CN' => 'China',
    'CX' => 'Christmas Island',
    'CC' => 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
    'CO' => 'Colombia',
    'KM' => 'Comoros the',
    'CD' => 'Congo',
    'CG' => 'Congo the',
    'CK' => 'Cook Islands',
    'CR' => 'Costa Rica',
    'CI' => 'Cote d\'Ivoire',
    'HR' => 'Croatia',
    'CU' => 'Cuba',
    'CY' => 'Cyprus',
    'CZ' => 'Czech Republic',
    'DK' => 'Denmark',
    'DJ' => 'Djibouti',
    'DM' => 'Dominica',
    'DO' => 'Dominican Republic',
    'EC' => 'Ecuador',
    'EG' => 'Egypt',
    'SV' => 'El Salvador',
    'GQ' => 'Equatorial Guinea',
    'ER' => 'Eritrea',
    'EE' => 'Estonia',
    'ET' => 'Ethiopia',
    'FO' => 'Faroe Islands',
    'FK' => 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
    'FJ' => 'Fiji the Fiji Islands',
    'FI' => 'Finland',
    'FR' => 'France, French Republic',
    'GF' => 'French Guiana',
    'PF' => 'French Polynesia',
    'TF' => 'French Southern Territories',
    'GA' => 'Gabon',
    'GM' => 'Gambia the',
    'GE' => 'Georgia',
    'DE' => 'Germany',
    'GH' => 'Ghana',
    'GI' => 'Gibraltar',
    'GR' => 'Greece',
    'GL' => 'Greenland',
    'GD' => 'Grenada',
    'GP' => 'Guadeloupe',
    'GU' => 'Guam',
    'GT' => 'Guatemala',
    'GG' => 'Guernsey',
    'GN' => 'Guinea',
    'GW' => 'Guinea-Bissau',
    'GY' => 'Guyana',
    'HT' => 'Haiti',
    'HM' => 'Heard Island and McDonald Islands',
    'VA' => 'Holy See (Vatican City State)',
    'HN' => 'Honduras',
    'HK' => 'Hong Kong',
    'HU' => 'Hungary',
    'IS' => 'Iceland',
    'IN' => 'India',
    'ID' => 'Indonesia',
    'IR' => 'Iran',
    'IQ' => 'Iraq',
    'IE' => 'Ireland',
    'IM' => 'Isle of Man',
    'IL' => 'Israel',
    'IT' => 'Italy',
    'JM' => 'Jamaica',
    'JP' => 'Japan',
    'JE' => 'Jersey',
    'JO' => 'Jordan',
    'KZ' => 'Kazakhstan',
    'KE' => 'Kenya',
    'KI' => 'Kiribati',
    'KP' => 'Korea',
    'KR' => 'Korea',
    'KW' => 'Kuwait',
    'KG' => 'Kyrgyz Republic',
    'LA' => 'Lao',
    'LV' => 'Latvia',
    'LB' => 'Lebanon',
    'LS' => 'Lesotho',
    'LR' => 'Liberia',
    'LY' => 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya',
    'LI' => 'Liechtenstein',
    'LT' => 'Lithuania',
    'LU' => 'Luxembourg',
    'MO' => 'Macao',
    'MK' => 'Macedonia',
    'MG' => 'Madagascar',
    'MW' => 'Malawi',
    'MY' => 'Malaysia',
    'MV' => 'Maldives',
    'ML' => 'Mali',
    'MT' => 'Malta',
    'MH' => 'Marshall Islands',
    'MQ' => 'Martinique',
    'MR' => 'Mauritania',
    'MU' => 'Mauritius',
    'YT' => 'Mayotte',
    'MX' => 'Mexico',
    'FM' => 'Micronesia',
    'MD' => 'Moldova',
    'MC' => 'Monaco',
    'MN' => 'Mongolia',
    'ME' => 'Montenegro',
    'MS' => 'Montserrat',
    'MA' => 'Morocco',
    'MZ' => 'Mozambique',
    'MM' => 'Myanmar',
    'NA' => 'Namibia',
    'NR' => 'Nauru',
    'NP' => 'Nepal',
    'AN' => 'Netherlands Antilles',
    'NL' => 'Netherlands the',
    'NC' => 'New Caledonia',
    'NZ' => 'New Zealand',
    'NI' => 'Nicaragua',
    'NE' => 'Niger',
    'NG' => 'Nigeria',
    'NU' => 'Niue',
    'NF' => 'Norfolk Island',
    'MP' => 'Northern Mariana Islands',
    'NO' => 'Norway',
    'OM' => 'Oman',
    'PK' => 'Pakistan',
    'PW' => 'Palau',
    'PS' => 'Palestinian Territory',
    'PA' => 'Panama',
    'PG' => 'Papua New Guinea',
    'PY' => 'Paraguay',
    'PE' => 'Peru',
    'PH' => 'Philippines',
    'PN' => 'Pitcairn Islands',
    'PL' => 'Poland',
    'PT' => 'Portugal, Portuguese Republic',
    'PR' => 'Puerto Rico',
    'QA' => 'Qatar',
    'RE' => 'Reunion',
    'RO' => 'Romania',
    'RU' => 'Russian Federation',
    'RW' => 'Rwanda',
    'BL' => 'Saint Barthelemy',
    'SH' => 'Saint Helena',
    'KN' => 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
    'LC' => 'Saint Lucia',
    'MF' => 'Saint Martin',
    'PM' => 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon',
    'VC' => 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
    'WS' => 'Samoa',
    'SM' => 'San Marino',
    'ST' => 'Sao Tome and Principe',
    'SA' => 'Saudi Arabia',
    'SN' => 'Senegal',
    'RS' => 'Serbia',
    'SC' => 'Seychelles',
    'SL' => 'Sierra Leone',
    'SG' => 'Singapore',
    'SK' => 'Slovakia (Slovak Republic)',
    'SI' => 'Slovenia',
    'SB' => 'Solomon Islands',
    'SO' => 'Somalia, Somali Republic',
    'ZA' => 'South Africa',
    'GS' => 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands',
    'ES' => 'Spain',
    'LK' => 'Sri Lanka',
    'SD' => 'Sudan',
    'SR' => 'Suriname',
    'SJ' => 'Svalbard & Jan Mayen Islands',
    'SZ' => 'Swaziland',
    'SE' => 'Sweden',
    'CH' => 'Switzerland, Swiss Confederation',
    'SY' => 'Syrian Arab Republic',
    'TW' => 'Taiwan',
    'TJ' => 'Tajikistan',
    'TZ' => 'Tanzania',
    'TH' => 'Thailand',
    'TL' => 'Timor-Leste',
    'TG' => 'Togo',
    'TK' => 'Tokelau',
    'TO' => 'Tonga',
    'TT' => 'Trinidad and Tobago',
    'TN' => 'Tunisia',
    'TR' => 'Turkey',
    'TM' => 'Turkmenistan',
    'TC' => 'Turks and Caicos Islands',
    'TV' => 'Tuvalu',
    'UG' => 'Uganda',
    'UA' => 'Ukraine',
    'AE' => 'United Arab Emirates',
    'GB' => 'United Kingdom',
    'US' => 'United States of America',
    'UM' => 'United States Minor Outlying Islands',
    'VI' => 'United States Virgin Islands',
    'UY' => 'Uruguay, Eastern Republic of',
    'UZ' => 'Uzbekistan',
    'VU' => 'Vanuatu',
    'VE' => 'Venezuela',
    'VN' => 'Vietnam',
    'WF' => 'Wallis and Futuna',
    'EH' => 'Western Sahara',
    'YE' => 'Yemen',
    'ZM' => 'Zambia',
    'ZW' => 'Zimbabwe'
];

    /**
     * @param string $countryName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIsoCodeByCountryName($countryName)
    {
        if (!isset(array_flip(self::COUNTRIES)[$countryName])) {
            trigger_error('Could not find country code ' . $countryName, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    
        return array_flip(self::COUNTRIES)[$countryName];
    }
}
```

And than call it where you need the class:

```
$countryCodes = new CountryIsoCodes();
$locations = array();

$args = array (
    'taxonomy' => 'location',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$get_locations = get_terms($args);

foreach ($get_locations as $key => $location) {
    $jobs_array = array();
    $location_name = $location->name;

// Get jobs
$post_type = 'jobs';
$posts_per_page = -1;
$jobs_args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'location' => $location_slug,
);

$jobs = new WP_Query( $jobs_args );

if($jobs->have_posts()) :
    while ( $jobs->have_posts() ): $jobs->the_post();
        // $jobs_array = $post;
        $jobs_array[] = $post->post_title;
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
endif;


$locations[$countryCodes->getIsoCodeByCountryName($location_slug)] = $jobs_array;
}
```

Hope it helps. Cheers

P.S. I have added an error trigger to the class, if the country name is not found. You can enrich the COUNTRIES constant with countries, if any is missing, or you are using a different name?

Please also check and adapt the country names, since they might be small differences with the one you have stored in DB... Ensure that they match ;)

Comment: Hi @alieni, this is indeed the way to do it, but I imported the countries as a taxonomy where the key is the name with dashes. I fixed it by adding an extra field to the taxonomy. Thanks anyway!